# how do I get the parent name in MDX query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mdx

I am trying to get the parent name of my agent list in the same row as the agency code, but I can't seem to get the right coding in the `with member` section

current code:

```
with
member Measures.[Parent Name] as [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember.parent
select
    {Measures.[Parent Name],
    [Measures].[Costs], 
    [Measures].[Revenue]} on columns,
    [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent] on rows
from 
    [Distribution]
```

but all I get in the `Parent Name` column is *#Error*

> VALUE  #Error Query (2, 34) The CURRENTMEMBER function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. A member expression was used.

I have also tried:

```
as [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember.properties("Agency Market")
as [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember.Parent.Member_Caption
as [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember.hierarchy.name
as ancestor([Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember,1)
as [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember.parent.name
as [Agent].[Agency_View].[Agency Agent].currentmember.parent.Member_Caption
```

Any other things for me to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever get a #Error cell in SSMS then double click it to get a better error.

In this case, I believe your Member_Caption attempt was close but you were trying to run the CurrentMember function on a level object not a hierarchy. Please try the following:

```
member Measures.[Parent Name] as [Agent].[Agency_View].CurrentMember.Parent.Member_Caption
```

Comment: @SeanC look closely. My MDX is slightly different than your 2nd attempt. The error message you posted confirms it was the problem I suspected.